# SQL find average number of tuples (neither max nor min)

Tags: sql, database, business-intelligence

Suppose I have two tables `PEOPLE` and `WORK`. I would like to find all the `work` with neither maximum nor minimum number of `people`.

EXAMPLE:

```
PEOPLE

ID NAME   WORK
1  Mark   Programmer
2  Sonia  Singer
3  Jack   Programmer
4  Mirco  Welder
5  Jeff   Welder
6  Tom    Welder

WORK

ID  WORK
1   Programmer
2   Singer
3   Welder
```

Result should be:

```
Programmer
```

How can I write a `MySQL query` like this??

Thank you all

---

You must consider that it is a kind of brain teaser. Than you surely will find a little set of 3 elements:

```
1 Maximum represented by Welder job done by Mirco, Jeff and Tom
2 Medium represented by Programmer done by Mark and Jack who is the Job I would like to find
3 Minimum represented by Singer done only from Sonia
```

Thank you

Comment: Don't now how others are, but I'm can't understand question

Comment: What flavour of SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way.  Find the min and max counts with a subquery and join that to another subquery with the count of each work.  Then left join and eliminate the rows that match the min or max count.

```
declare @people table (id int, name varchar(20), work varchar(50))
insert into @people
values (1,  'Mark'  , 'Programmer'),
(2,  'Sonia'  ,'Singer'),
(3,  'Jack',   'Programmer'),
(4,  'Mirco',  'Welder'),
(5,  'Jeff',   'Welder'),
(6,  'Tom',    'Welder')

select a.work
from ( -- A subquery that returns the count of each work
   select work, count(*) cnt
   from @people
   group by work
) a
left outer join ( -- a subquery that returns the min and max counts
   select min(cnt) mincount, max(cnt) maxcount
   from (
      select count(*) cnt
      from @people
      group by work
   ) b
) c
   on a.cnt = c.mincount
   or a.cnt = c.maxcount
where c.mincount is null
```

Comment: This is pretty much the same solution as @Nick, only with derived tables instead of CTEs.

Comment: This is the only one solution that works with the `MySql` version of HackerRank Test Page!!. In fact that version doesn't support `limit` or other `declarations` or `function` wrote in the solution below. Thanks man!!

Answer (score 1):

This query will work on flavours of SQL that support CTEs (e.g. SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL 8+):

```
WITH counts AS
(SELECT WORK, COUNT(*) AS num
 FROM people
 GROUP BY WORK),
minmax AS 
(SELECT MIN(num) AS min, MAX(num) AS max
 FROM counts)
SELECT WORK
FROM counts c
JOIN minmax m ON c.num != m.min AND c.num != m.max
```

Output:

```
WORK
Programmer
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=5f58a45b6f52563d4b76d57482637f08)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that uses window functions:

- first use an aggregate query to compute the number of people for each work
- then rank the works by ascending and descending people count
- finally, filter out the top and bottom records

Query:

```
SELECT work
FROM (
    SELECT 
        work,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY cnt) rn_asc,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY cnt DESC) rn_desc
    FROM (
        SELECT work, COUNT(*) cnt FROM people GROUP BY work
    ) x
) x WHERE rn_asc != 1 AND rn_desc != 1
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kbMnPh7MT14B7ER2n1KXne/0)**:

```
| work       |
| ---------- |
| Programmer |
```

Note: as far as concerns, you don't need to query the `work` table to get the expected results since all relevant information is available in `people`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this without window functions:

```
select w.*
from work w
where w.work not in (select p.work
                     from people p
                     group by p.work
                     order by count(*) asc
                     fetch first 1 row only
                    ) and
      w.work not in (select p.work
                     from people p
                     group by p.work
                     order by count(*) desc
                     fetch first 1 row only
                    );
```

Note that in the event of duplicates, this only considers one row the minimum/maximum so ties can be returned.